# Move CNTRL PGUP to switch between Excel sheets without having to repeatedly press CNTRL

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I've made it so CNTRL + END switches to the worksheet to the left in Excel but I can't hold down on CNTRL and just repeat the pressing of END. How can I replicate fully the CNTRL + PGUP switch method. THANKS!!!

```
 Sub ReassKey()
     Application.OnKey "^{END}", "Personal.xlsb!SendCNTRLPGUPKey"
 End Sub

Sub SendCNTRLPGUPKey()
     SendKeys "^{PGUP}"
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub SendCNTRLPGUPKey()
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> Sheets(1).Name Then ActiveSheet.Previous.Activate
End Sub
```

Notice that the first **visible** sheet will get reactivated if there are some hidden sheets to the left of it.

Comment: THANKS! Kapol, your suggestion worked perfectly. You made my day!

Comment: Is there a way to make this and or any ReassKey() Application.OnKey work in once you are in the Formula Bar, i.e, it works great before you've clicked into a cell, but is deactivated once inside.

Comment: No. You cannot interact with Excel/VBA while editing a cell's value.